# How to read json file in CKEditor plugin synchronous

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I need to create a customs plugin for CKEditor 5 that will read a JSON and will show data in a dropdown list in the toolbar.
the problem I faced is async fetching data which is not finished before setting the list into the configuration in the Init method.

```
export default class PlaceholderEditing extends Plugin {
static get requires() {
    return [Widget];
}

init() {
    
    this._defineSchema();
    this._defineConverters();

    this.editor.commands.add('placeholder', new PlaceholderCommand(this.editor));

    this.editor.editing.mapper.on(
        'viewToModelPosition',
        viewToModelPositionOutsideModelElement(this.editor.model, viewElement => viewElement.hasClass('placeholder'))
    );

    var items=new Array();

    fetch('/GetTerms').then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);       
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        items = data;
    });


    this.editor.config.define('placeholderConfig', {
        types: items
    });



}
```

in this code items always is null because config define is run before the fetch is finished.
I couldn't put config.define in the then clause because init method will be finished before it.

So, how can I force fetch to wait for the result or better to say how can I fetch data sync not async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solve my problem by adding async function into my constructor

```
init() {
    return (async () => {

        this._defineSchema();
        this._defineConverters();

        this.editor.commands.add('placeholder', new PlaceholderCommand(this.editor));

        this.editor.editing.mapper.on(
            'viewToModelPosition',
            viewToModelPositionOutsideModelElement(this.editor.model, viewElement => viewElement.hasClass('placeholder'))
        );

        var items = new Array();

        await fetch('contractTerms.json').then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data.items);
            items = data.items;
        });

        console.log('pass');
        this.editor.config.define('placeholderConfig', {
            types: items
        });
      })();
```